# Заменить все символы в строке std::string заданным символом

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, строки, stl, str-replace

Подскажите как оптимально (если есть возможность - средствами STL) заменить в строку набор символов на некоторый символ.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
std::wstring author;
std::replace(author.begin(), author.end(), L'.', L' ');
std::replace(author.begin(), author.end(), L',', L' ');
std::replace(author.begin(), author.end(), L'-', L' ');
std::replace(author.begin(), author.end(), L'\t', L' ');
```

Но хотелось бы (если такое возможно) сделать оптимальный, быстрый и при том компактный код (например, в 1 строку). Возможно через регулярки это можно сделать, то без понятия как.

Comment: Вряд ли `wstring+stl+регулярки` совместимо с `быстрый и при том компактный`

Comment: согласен на понятный и компактный :)

Comment: Я бы сделал простой цикл `for (...) { wchar_t c = author[i]; switch (c) { case L'.' : c = L'  '; break; ... } author[i] = c; }` и никому (а в первую очередь компайлеру) не морочил голову

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если хочется использовать стандартные алгоритмы, то лучше уж так:

```
std::replace_if(author.begin(), author.end(),
    [](wchar_t c){return c == L'.' || c == L',' || c == L'-' || c == L'\t';}, L' ');
```

Comment: Так как изначально объект имеет тип std::wstring, то было бы правильнее вместо параметра char c записать в лямбда выражение следующий параметр const auto &c.

Comment: это конечно так, но думал, что есть что-то типа
`std::replace(begin, end, L'.,-\t', L' ')`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Как минимум там должен был быть `wchar_t`, поправил.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать как стандартный алгоритм `std::replace_if`, так и цикл `for` на основе диапазона, а также собственные методы класса `std::wstring`.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, показывающая перечисленные способы замены символов. В программе используется манипулятор `std::quoted`, который появился в C++17. Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает его, то просто замените выражение `std::quoted( s )` на `s`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::wstring s( L"Hello-World." );

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    std::replace_if( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ),
                     []( const auto &c ) 
                     { return c == L'.' or c == L',' or c == L'-' or c == '\t'; },
                     L' ' );

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    std::wcout << '\n';

    s.assign( L"Hello-World." );

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    for ( auto &c : s )
    {
        switch ( c )
        {
        case L'.':
        case L',':
        case L'-':
        case L'\t':
            c = L' ';
            break;
        }
    }

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';
    std::wcout << '\n';

    s.assign( L"Hello-World." );

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    for ( std::wstring::size_type n = 0; 
          ( n = s.find_first_of( L".,-\t", n ) ) != std::wstring::npos;
          ++n )
    {
        s.replace( n, 1, 1, L' ' );         
    }       

    std::wcout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';
    std::wcout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
"Hello-World."
"Hello World "

"Hello-World."
"Hello World "

"Hello-World."
"Hello World "
```

Для меток предложения `switch` можно использовать атрибут `fallthrough`, чтобы избежать ненужных предупреждений компилятора. Например,

```
for ( auto &c : s )
{
    switch ( c )
    {
    case L'.':
    [[fallthrough]];
    case L',':
    [[fallthrough]];
    case L'-':
    [[fallthrough]];
    case L'\t':
        c = L' ';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное лучше использовать методы класса. Ведь для того и они предназначены:

```
wstring  d(L".,-\t");
size_t  cur = 0;
while (true) {
    cur = autor.find_first_of(d, cur);
    if (cur == wstring::npos)  break;
    autor.replace(cur, 1, 1, L' ');         
}
```